# Stripe 3D secure payment on live is not working

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, stripe-payments, 3d-secure

I trying to connect 3D secure payment for a website, it is working fine in test environment with test cards but when I switched with live keys, it is not generating pop up to user for confirmation. it complete the payment without confirmation.
through this i get the client secret key

```
$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    'amount'   =>  $amount * 100,
    'currency' => $results->currency,
    'payment_method' => $paymentMethodId,
    'confirmation_method' => 'automatic',
    'description' => "Booking",
    'customer' => $user_stripe_customer,
    'receipt_email' => $user->email,
]);
```

On clients Side

```
  formsub.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                // Create a FormData object to gather form data
                const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);

                // Convert form data to a plain JavaScript object
                const submitData = Object.fromEntries(formData);


                // Disable the button and change its appearance
                bookBtn.disabled = true;
                bookBtn.innerText = 'Loading';
                bookBtn.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';

                // Create a PaymentMethod with Stripe
                stripe.createPaymentMethod({
                    type: 'card',
                    card: card,
                }).then(function(result) {
                    if (result.error) {
                        console.error(result.error.message);
                        bookBtn.disabled = false;
                        bookBtn.innerText = 'Book Now';
                        bookBtn.style.backgroundColor = '';
                        errorCard.innerHTML =
                            `<p style="color:red;">Error: ${result.error.message}</p>`;
                    } else {
                        // Call your server to create a PaymentIntent
                        fetch('/payment', {
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                            },
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                data: submitData,
                                payment_method: result.paymentMethod.id,
                            }), // Sending data as JSON
                        }).then(function(response) {
                            return response.json();
                        }).then(function(data) {
                            if (data.client_secret) {
                                stripe.confirmCardPayment(data.client_secret, {
                                    payment_method: result.paymentMethod.id,
                                }).then(function(confirmResult) {
                                    if (confirmResult.error) {
                                        handleConfirmError(confirmResult);
                                    } else {
                                        handlePaymentSuccess(confirmResult
                                            .paymentIntent);
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                errorCard.innerHTML =
                                    `<p style="color:red;">Error: ${data.message}</p>`;
                                // Reset button appearance after an error
                                bookBtn.disabled = false;
                                bookBtn.innerText = 'Book Now';
                                bookBtn.style.backgroundColor = '';
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

            function handleConfirmError(confirmResult) {

                if (confirmResult.error.payment_intent &&
                    confirmResult.error.payment_intent.status === 'requires_action') {
                    // Handle 3D Secure authentication
                    stripe.handleCardAction(confirmResult.error.payment_intent.client_secret)
                        .then(function(actionResult) {
                            if (actionResult.error) {
                                console.error(actionResult.error.message);
                                bookBtn.disabled = false;
                                bookBtn.innerText = 'Book Now';
                                bookBtn.style.backgroundColor = '';
                                errorCard.innerHTML =
                                    `<p style="color:red;">Error: ${actionResult.error.message}</p>`;
                            } else {
                                // Re-confirm the PaymentIntent after 3D Secure
                                stripe.confirmCardPayment(confirmResult.error.payment_intent.client_secret, {
                                    payment_method: result.paymentMethod.id,
                                }).then(function(result) {
                                    if (result.error) {
                                        console.error(result.error.message);
                                        errorCard.innerHTML =
                                            `<p style="color:red;">Error: ${result.error.message}</p>`;
                                        // Reset button appearance after an error
                                        bookBtn.disabled = false;
                                        bookBtn.innerText = 'Book Now';
                                        bookBtn.style.backgroundColor = '';
                                    } else {
                                        // Payment succeeded, redirect or show success message
                                        console.log(result.paymentIntent);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                } else {
                    console.error(confirmResult.error.message);
                    errorCard.innerHTML = `<p style="color:red;">Error: ${confirmResult.error.message}</p>`;
                    // Reset button appearance after an error
                    bookBtn.disabled = false;
                    bookBtn.innerText = 'Book Now';
                    bookBtn.style.backgroundColor = '';
                }
            }
```

I know some cards don't support 3D but i use a card on other site and it did 3D payment from that site.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally depends on the card issuer to request or doesn't request 3DS on a specific transaction (they hold the final decision).

Your code shouldn't have any issue, but you can look at [Stripe Radar setting](https://stripe.com/docs/radar/rules#request-3d-secure) to loosen the 3DS rules, ie. using "Request 3D Secure if 3D Secure is recommended for card" to request 3DS most frequent as possible.

Comment: do we need to set the stripe Radar setting in our app aswell? or stripe catches from its own dashboard?

Comment: Stripe will take what value you set on your Stripe Dashboard